# getting error while deserializing yaml file

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, yaml, yamldotnet

There is no problem with serialize but deserializing throw error like below. I shared all related classes and error. What should I do to deserialize this file.

yaml file (created by yaml serializing) :

```
  Edits:   0:
        Id: 20
        Type: AddOrUpdate
        Operation:
          book:
            ElementName: a
            ArithmeticExpression: asd
            ConditionExpression: a
```

c# classes :

```
 public class DbContext
        {
            public Dictionary<int, DbModel> Edits { get; set; }
        }



      public class DbModel
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, Operation> Operation { get; set; }


            public DbModel(int id, string type, Dictionary<string, Operation> op)
            {
                Id = id;
                Type = type;
                Operation = op;
            }
        }
    public class Operation
    {
        public string ElementName { get; set; }
        public string ArithmeticExpression { get; set; }
        public string ConditionExpression { get; set; }

        public Operation(string elemName, string ArithmetticExp, string ConditionExp)
        {
            ElementName = elemName;
            ArithmeticExpression = ArithmetticExp;
            ConditionExpression = ConditionExp;
        }

    }

class DatabaseOperation
{
    public static DbContext DbContext { get; set; }
    public const string yamlEditString = "C:\\Data\\setting.yml";

    static DatabaseOperation()
    {
        DbContext = ReadAllDataFromFile().Result;
    }

    public static Task<DbContext> ReadAllDataFromFile()
    {
        DbContext dbCon = new DbContext();
        if (File.Exists(yamlEditString))
        {

            var deserializer = new Deserializer();

            string readedData = File.ReadAllText(yamlEditString);
            //dbCon.Edits = deserializer.Deserialize<List<DbModel>>(readedData);
            try
            {
                dbCon = deserializer.Deserialize<DbContext>(readedData);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            dbCon.Edits = new Dictionary<int, DbModel>();
        }
        return Task.FromResult(dbCon);
    }
    public static Task WriteAllDataToFile(DbContext dbCon)
    {
        var serializer = new Serializer();
        File.WriteAllText(yamlEditString, serializer.Serialize(dbCon));
    }
}
```

> getting this error :
>   (Line: 7, Col: 9, Idx: 86) - (Line: 7, Col: 9, Idx: 86): Exception during deserialization

"YamlDotNet"

inner exception :

> Failed to create an instance of type 'YamlEdit.Operation'.
>
> at
>   YamlDotNet.Serialization.ObjectFactories.DefaultObjectFactory.Create(Type
>   type)    at
>   YamlDotNet.Serialization.NodeDeserializers.ObjectNodeDeserializer.YamlDotNet.Serialization.INodeDeserializer.Deserialize(IParser
>   parser, Type expectedType, Func`3 nestedObjectDeserializer, Object&
>   value)    at
>   YamlDotNet.Serialization.ValueDeserializers.NodeValueDeserializer.DeserializeValue(IParser
>   parser, Type expectedType, SerializerState state, IValueDeserializer
>   nestedObjectDeserializer)

StackTrace :

```
   at YamlDotNet.Serialization.ValueDeserializers.NodeValueDeserializer.DeserializeValue(IParser parser, Type expectedType, SerializerState state, IValueDeserializer nestedObjectDeserializer)
   at YamlDotNet.Serialization.ValueDeserializers.AliasValueDeserializer.DeserializeValue(IParser parser, Type expectedType, SerializerState state, IValueDeserializer nestedObjectDeserializer)
   at YamlDotNet.Serialization.ValueDeserializers.NodeValueDeserializer.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<DeserializeValue>b__0(IParser r, Type t)
   at YamlDotNet.Serialization.NodeDeserializers.DictionaryNodeDeserializer.DeserializeHelper(Type tKey, Type tValue, IParser parser, Func`3 nestedObjectDeserializer, IDictionary result)
   at YamlDotNet.Serialization.NodeDeserializers.DictionaryNodeDeserializer.YamlDotNet.Serialization.INodeDeserializer.Deserialize(IParser parser, Type expectedType, Func`3 nestedObjectDeserializer, Object& value)
   at YamlDotNet.Serialization.ValueDeserializers.NodeValueDeserializer.DeserializeValue(IParser parser, Type expectedType, SerializerState state, IValueDeserializer nestedObjectDeserializer)
   at YamlDotNet.Serialization.ValueDeserializers.AliasValueDeserializer.DeserializeValue(IParser parser, Type expectedType, SerializerState state, IValueDeserializer nestedObjectDeserializer)
   at YamlDotNet.Serialization.ValueDeserializers.NodeValueDeserializer.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<DeserializeValue>b__0(IParser r, Type t)
   at YamlDotNet.Serialization.NodeDeserializers.ObjectNodeDeserializer.YamlDotNet.Serialization.INodeDeserializer.Deserialize(IParser parser, Type expectedType, Func`3 nestedObjectDeserializer, Object& value)
   at YamlDotNet.Serialization.ValueDeserializers.NodeValueDeserializer.DeserializeValue(IParser parser, Type expectedType, SerializerState state, IValueDeserializer nestedObjectDeserializer)
   at YamlDotNet.Serialization.ValueDeserializers.AliasValueDeserializer.DeserializeValue(IParser parser, Type expectedType, SerializerState state, IValueDeserializer nestedObjectDeserializer)
   at YamlDotNet.Serialization.Deserializer.Deserialize(IParser parser, Type type)
   at YamlDotNet.Serialization.Deserializer.Deserialize[T](String input)
   at YamlEdit.DatabaseOperation.ReadAllDataFromFile() in D:\Repositories\YamlEdit\DatabaseOperation.cs:line 35
```

Comment: I think there are missing parts of the stack trace that tell what actually went wrong.

Comment: added stackTrace

Comment: Constructor cause an error. When I delete the constructor, deserialize yaml file correctly.

Comment: Yeah, but I think there should be some more specific error description than *Exception during deserialization* somewhere in the stack trace. I may be wrong, not having that much experience with YamlDotNet.

Comment: Just a thought: Maybe YamlDotNet has a problem with the property `Operation` having the same name as the class `Operation`. Unlikely, but may be worth a try.

Comment: I didn't change property or class names. Still working correctly after add empty constructor to Operation Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a parameterless constructor to the `YamlEdit.Operation`. YamlDotNet does not know how to pass constructors parameters.